# Pairing elements to obtain maximum number of even sums

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

Given a circular array of N integers (that is, A[0] and A[N - 1] are adjacent to each other), what's the maximum number of adjacent
pairs that you can form whose sum are even? Note that each element can belong to at most one pair.

For example, if we have [5, 7, 9, 6, 3], then you should pair (5, 3) and (7, 9) to achieve the answer of two. Also, if we have [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], then the answer is 3 (pair each adjacent element without wrapping around)

This is a recent problem that I encountered in an interview, and I still can't solve it (I didn't get the job). I know that the sum of two numbers of the same parity produce an even sum (so odd and odd, or even and even), but the whole "wrap-around" part is what's getting me. In particular, I can't figure out whether or not it's optimal to pair a value with its left neighbor or its right neighbor. The current algorithm I'm thinking of is as follows:

- For each index 0 <= i <= n - 1, try to pair A[i] with A[i + 1] by checking their parity.
- If both A[0] and A[n-1] are unpaired at the end, pair them if they have the same parity.

This is a wrong algorithm since it fails for [1, 1, 1, 0, 1] in which case it's optimal to pair A[0] with A[n-1] and A[1] with A[2]. Does anyone have any suggestions? I was thinking perhaps something with dynamic programming, but I'm not sure. The circular part is really throwing me off.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If all numbers are odd, or all numbers are even, then

- if array length is even, include all numbers (it doesn't matter how you group).
- if it is odd, include all numbers except the smallest one.

If there are both odd and even numbers, then you can partition the array into odd runs and even runs. Concatenate the first and the last run if they are both even or both odd. Solve the problem for each run separately. It is easy because the runs are NOT circular. If the length of the run is even, include all numbers. Otherwise, exclude the smallest number at an *even* position.

This assumes that all numbers are non-negative.

Comment: That makes sense. So we partition the array into even/odd runs of maximal length, and each run of length `x` contributes `floor(x/2)` to the answer?

Comment: Can you explain what is a `run`?

Comment: I think they meant a group of consecutive integers of maximal length all of which are even or all of which are odd

Answer (score 0):

```
int solution(vector<int> A) {
    int n = A.size();
    
    int ans1 = 0, ans2 = 0;
    {
        vector<int> dp(n, 0);
        for(int i = 1;i<n;i++){
            if((A[i] + A[i-1]) % 2 == 0){
                dp[i] = max(dp[i], 1 + ((i-2>=0)?dp[i-2]:0));
            }
            ans1 = max(ans1, dp[i]);
        }
    }
    {
        A.push_back(A[0]);
        A.erase(A.begin());
        vector<int> dp(n, 0);
        for(int i = 1;i<n;i++){

            if((A[i] + A[i-1]) % 2 == 0){
                dp[i] = max(dp[i], 1 + ((i-2>=0)?dp[i-2]:0));
            }
            ans2 = max(ans2, dp[i]);
        }
    }

    return max(ans1, ans2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**